# shared_ptr in c++, getting points to faces

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, shared-ptr

I have the following class for points:

```
class MyPoint
{
    public:
    
        // Constructor
        MyPoint(double, double, double);

        // Destructor
        virtual ~MyPoint(){};

    protected:

    private:
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;

};
```

I would like to create a vector of myPoints to store some data:

```
vector <MyPoint> vectorOfPoints

for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    vectorOfPoints.push_back(MyPoint(1,2,3));
}
```

And I would like to create a class called myFaces to store the address of the points that make up a face.

e.g.,

Face A is built with vectorOfPoints[0], vectorOfPoints[2],  vectorOfPoints[5] and  vectorOfPoints[6].

How can I pass a vector with the addresses of the above entries to the class myFace?

```
class myFace
{
    public:

        // Constructor  
        myFace(int, vector<std::shared_ptr<Point> > );

        // Destructor
        virtual  ~myFace(){};
       
         
    protected:

    private:
        int nPointsInFace_;
        vector<std::shared_ptr<Point> > refToPointsThatMakeUpThisFace_;
  
};
```

Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: If your hope is to used `std::shared_ptr` to link a `myFace` to the `std::vector<Point>` where the points reside, it's not going to happen. If the external vector was `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Point>>` it could certainly (and easily) be done.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to exemplify? The initial approach was in fact to link the std::vector<Point> to the myFace

Comment: Jon's answer below *exactly* describes the problem and solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Face A is built with vectorOfPoints[0], vectorOfPoints[2], vectorOfPoints[5] and vectorOfPoints[6].

You want indexes. So store that!

```
class myFace
{
    vector<size_t> indexes_;

    public:
        myFace(vector<size_t>) ...
};
```

You don't need `nPointsInFace_` because its the size of `indexes_`.

You can use a smaller type if you know you dont need so many, like `uint16_t`.

You avoid messing with pointers (and `shared_ptr` which is overkill for single 3D points).

You can do checked accesses.

Comment: but If I change the coordinate of a point, the value in the face will not change with this implementation, right?

Comment: It will. There is no point in the face, only the index.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest answer is to change your vector of points to a vector of pointers to points. Something like this:

```
vector <std::shared_ptr<MyPoint>> vectorOfPoints;

for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    vectorOfPoints.push_back(std::make_shared<MyPoint>(1,2,3));
}
```

Now you can very easily just cherry pick whichever points you want to pass to your `myFace` constructor. Using managed pointers like `std::shared_ptr` is an all-or-nothing proposition.

Comment: Using thread-safe smart pointers to store single 3D points is overkill and will kill performance.

Comment: 100% agreed @Acorn. Always the risk of directly answering SO questions without having a conversation around it.

Answer (score 0):

What if I put something like

```
class myFace
{
    public:

        // Constructor  
        myFace(int, vector<myPoint*>);

        // Destructor
        virtual  ~myFace(){};
       
         
    protected:

    private:
        int nPointsInFace_;
        vector<myPoint*> refToPointsThatMakeUpThisFace_;
  
};
```

After initializing the vectorOfPoints. If I can

```
std::vector<Point*> listOfPoints (4); 

listOfPoints[0] = vectorOfPoints[0]
listOfPoints[1] = vectorOfPoints[2]
listOfPoints[2] = vectorOfPoints[5]
listOfPoints[3] = vectorOfPoints[6]

Face myFace (4, listOfPoints);
```

This should create a face with the address of the vectorOfPoints, no?
More classes will have pointers the vectorOfPoints, is makes sense to use a shared_ptr, right?

Comment: use `std::initializer_list` to initialize as you do with vector.

Comment: Would shared_ptr be a good option in this situation?

Comment: smart pointers are always a better option than raw pointer. Said that, for what do you want to achieve you should provide a constructor accepting a std::initializer_list

Comment: In a actual practice this will be placed inside a for loop to store the address. Does a  std::initializer_list make sense in that situation?